# Xcode15 error clang:1:1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) but didn't happen in Xcode 14.3.1

Tags: xcode

When i ues Xcode Version 15.0 (15A240d) to run my project on my iphone, i got error like:
`ld: 54 duplicate symbols`
```` ld:1:1: no platform load command found in '```.o)', assuming: iOS ````
`clang:1:1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`
But it didn't happen in Xcode 14.3.1. Does anyone know how to do with tihs problem? Need i downgrade to Xcode 14.3.1？But how to do it under Sonoma 14

Does anyone know how to do with tihs problem?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 15 includes a new linker, known as `ld_prime`, which has become more strict in some aspects. For example, some duplicate symbols used to be warnings but are now errors.

While it is still possible to switch back to the old linker (for now) by adding `-Wl,-ld_classic` to the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting, it is advisable to eliminate duplicate symbols when time permits.